# Barcodescanner plugin is not being initialized in window.plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've already added the barcodescanner plugin to my phonegap project. It seems it's not being initialized in window.plugins, it appears like 'undefined'.

I am testing it in eclipse - android sdk.

Here's my code where I suppose it writes in window.plugins

```
ScannerLoader(require, exports, module);
    cordova.define("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner", ScannerLoader);

    if (! window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }

    if (! window.plugins.LocalNotification) {
        //window.plugins.LocalNotification = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/LocalNotification");
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
    }
```

I am using phonegap 2.9.0 and my OS is Mac OSX Mavericks

**EDIT:** I also noticed the plugin calls require() javascript function which browser cannot recognize. Do I have to add another js file so require() function works?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. Make sure your plugin is initialized in cordova project:

cordova.define( "cordova/plugin/barcodescanner", function( require, exports, module ){ .. });

1. Make sure window.plugins exists like object, else create it.

   if (!window.plugins) {
       window.plugins = {};
   }
2. Assign the plugin to window.plugins

   if (!window.plugins.barcodeScanner) {
       window.plugins.barcodeScanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/barcodescanner");
   }